# Hyperref and nested \glsxtrshort and \glsfmtlong

Tags: hyperref, glossaries, glossaries-extra

The `glossaries-extra` manual recomends the use of `\glsxtrshort` and friends, when cross-referencing other acronyms in the definition of an acronym. This mechanism, however, appears to break when used together with `\glsfmtlong` and  `hyperref`, as illustrated by the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries-extra}

\newabbreviation{ara}{ARA}{a random abbreviation}
\newabbreviation{aaca}{AACA}{another abbreviation containing \glsxtrshort{ara}}

\begin{document}

\section{Section with \glsfmtlong{aaca}}

Text

\end{document}
```

When compiling, `hyperref` complains about the command `\glsxtrshort`:

```
Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
(hyperref)                removing `\glsxtrshort' on input line 10.
```

Accordingly, in the PDF navigation the section title is displayed as "Section with another abbreviation containing ara", i.e. "ara" is not looked up to result in "ARA".

It appears that `\glsxtrshort` *should* be expandable, thus causing no trouble for `hyperref`, but for some reason this fails. How can I refer to other acronyms properly without losing the hyperref functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the short description like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries-extra}

\newabbreviation{ara}{ARA}{a random abbreviation}
\newabbreviation{aaca}{AACA}{another abbreviation containing \glsxtrshort{ara}}
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
  \def\glsxtrshort#1{\csname glo@#1@short\endcsname}%
}
\begin{document}


\section{Section with \glsfmtlong{aaca}}

Text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @UlrikeFischer So you are basically stripping off `\protect` to make `\glsxtrshort` expandable, just for hyperref, correct?

Comment: I redefine the command for hyperref yes.

Comment: Is there a similar solution you can come up with for `\glsxtrshortpl`? I tried looking at its expansion and it seems that it is defined by some option checking plus `\ns@glsxtrshortpl`, which again is protected, but I don't understand the definition of the latter.

Comment: My first try  (before checking the code) would be `\csname glo@#1@shortpl\endcsname`

Comment: Yes, indeed that is the solution. So simple, that I didn't think about trying it. :-)